# how to change a sprite on the screen after pressing a key in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm new to Pygame, and still learning Python. I'm using Python 3.4. 
I followed this amazing game creation tutorial: http://pythonprogramming.net/pygame-python-3-part-1-intro/. After completing the lessons I decided to change the game slightly, and have succeeded in adding some more movement and fixed some bugs. However now I'm trying to figure out how to change the sprite when I press an arrow key, as to make it appear like it is tilting.

I have a file called `racecar.png` (which is the plane) and `move_right.png` (which looks like it is tilted). My end goal is to have it when I press the right arrow, `move_right.png` is displayed until I release the key, in which case it returns to `racecar.png`. I have looked up how to use sprite sheets, which failed, how to animate, watched YouTube, Googled my problem but I can't find anyone else who has this problem. Most of what I found talked about moving the sprite around the screen.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()

car_width = 100
car_height = 100

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A Macross Simumater')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
greent = (0, 150, 0)
blue = (0,0, 200)
dark_blue = (0, 0, 50)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImp = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')

gameIcon = pygame.image.load('caricon.png')

#background = pygame.image.load('background.png')

pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def unpause():
    global pause
    pause = False

def paused():

    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        button("Continue",150,450,100,50,green,black,unpause)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,black,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)   


def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: " + str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImp, (x, y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()

def crash():


    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115, (0, 0, 0))
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("You Crashed", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        button("Play Again",150,450,100,50,green,black,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,black,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15) 

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac, action = None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x, y, w, h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x, y, w, h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 21)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects("GO!", smallText)
    textRect.center = ((150+(100/2)), (450+(50/2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

    textSurf, textRect = text_objects("QUIT!", smallText)
    textRect.center = ((550+(100/2)), (450+(50/2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects('Macross',largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        button("GO!", 150, 450, 100, 50, green, black, game_loop)
        button("Quit", 550,450,100,50, red, black, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def game_loop():
    global pause

    pygame.mixer.music.load('Macross Plus - Voices HQ MV Karaoke Instrumental Japanese.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    global x_change
    global y_change

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0


    pause = False

    dodged = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 4
    thing_width = 50
    thing_height = 50

    thingt_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thingt_starty = -600
    thingt_speed = 7
    thingt_width = 100
    thingt_height = 100


    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True


            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 8
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -8
                elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    pause = True
                    paused()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -8
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 8
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    x_change = 0
                    y_change = 0

        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(dark_blue)

        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, greent)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        things(thingt_startx, thingt_starty, thingt_width, thingt_height, greent)
        thingt_starty += thingt_speed

        car(x, y)


        if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
            crash()
        if y > display_width - car_width or y < 0:
            y_change = 0

        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1
            thing_width += (dodged * 1.2)
            thing_height += (dodged * 2)
            thingt_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thingt_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thingt_speed += 1
            thingt_width += (dodged * 1.2)
            thingt_height += (dodged * 2)

        if thing_starty < y:
            if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
                if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx + thing_width:
                    crash()
        elif thing_starty > y:
            print('passed')

        if thingt_starty < y:
            if y < thingt_starty+thingt_height:
                if x > thingt_startx and x < thingt_startx + thingt_width or x +     car_width > thingt_startx and x + car_width < thingt_startx + thingt_width:
                    crash()
        elif thingt_starty > y:
            print('PASSED')





        things_dodged(dodged)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)



game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

At each frame, you display the image in the global variable called `carImp` in this function:

```
def car(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImp, (x, y))
```

SO, what you have to do is to *change* the contents of this variable to point to the desired image before the display.
You should first read all the images for your car – you  can read them all into a dictionary to avoid polluting your namespace (even more than it is polluted) with a variable name for each sprite:

So, in the beginning, some code like:

```
car_image_names = ["racecar", "move_right", "move_left"]
car_sprites = dict(((img_name, pygame.image.load(img_name + ".png"))
                        for img_name in car_image_names)
carImp = car_sprites["racecar"]
```

(Here I've used a shortcut called "generator expression" to avoid having to write a "pygame.image.load" for each car image.)

And then, in your main loop, after you've read the keyboard, and detected
whether the car is moving right or left (which you reflect in `x_change`) – just change  `carImp` accordingly:

```
if x_change == 0:
    carImp = car_sprites["racecar"]
elif x_change > 0:
    carImp = car_sprites["move_right"]
elif x_change < 0:
    carImp = car_sprites["move_left"]
```